# How to Authenticate a PR within Azure Pipelines when checkout occurs for a different repo from the pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-authentication, azure-repos

I have a desire to create a pipeline that will automate the process of creating a new version for a Hotfix.

This Pipeline will do the following

1. Check out a repo
2. Create a Branch off of that Repo
3. REGEX replace text in a file in that repo
4. Commit the changes to the branch
5. Push the branch to AzDo
6. Create a pull Request of that branch into another.

I have been able to get the above to work when the yaml file for the pipeline is in the same repo as the file we are creating a branch for and manipulating, but when it is in a different repo (ie something other than checkout:self) I will get an error.

Below is a slightly stripped down and anonymized version of my (working) yaml. I have removed a lot of the interactive pieces to make it as bare bones as possible for clarity. Note that this yaml file is stored in repoA

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
  - group: Secure-PAT

jobs:
  - job: update_version_job
    displayName: "Update Version Job"
    steps:
      - checkout: git://PROJECT/repoA@master
        persistCredentials: true

      - script: echo $(System.AccessToken) | az devops login
        displayName: 'Login to DevOps'

      - script: |
          git config --global user.email "Email@script.com"
          git config --global user.name "Hotfix Script"
          git fetch --all
          git checkout -b hotfix-branch
        displayName: 'Set Git Identifiers'

      - task: RegexReplace@3
        displayName: 'Edit Revision Version'
        inputs:
          InputSearchPattern: 'versions.txt'
          FindRegex: '(name\: revision\s+value\:)( \''\d+)(\'')'
          ReplaceRegex: $1 '$(revision)'
          UseUTF8: true
          UseRAW: true

      - script: git commit -am "Increment version"
        displayName: 'Commit Changes'

      - script: git push https://$(user-pat)@dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION/PROJECT/_git/repoA hotfix-branch
        displayName: 'Push Branch'

      - script: az repos pr create  --source-branch hotfix-branch --target-branch release/hotfix
        displayName: 'Create PR'
```

However, if I had an identical file in repoB I wanted to update as well, exactly the same as above, and I simply replace all instance of `repoA` with `repoB` I will get an error when attempting to login reporting `Unable to use secure credential store in this environment`
[image: Picture of Initial Failure]

I then followed the suggestion here (https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/25247#issuecomment-1532586608) and added

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: '$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = ''$(System.AccessToken)'''
```

as the first post checkout step. This got me further, but when attempting to do the final step of creating the PR the following error would occur:

`ERROR: Before you can run Azure DevOps commands, you need to run the login command(az login if using AAD/MSA identity else az devops login if using PAT token) to setup credentials.  Please see https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth for more information.`

Trying to login with the system Access Token just before the PR will obviously just give the same error as originally, attempting to use

```
- script: az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/ORGANIZATION/
  displayName: 'Login to DevOps'
```

Right before the PR step did not alleviate issues, as that login failed: `ERROR: Failed to authenticate using the supplied token.`

I then tried to add a personal PAT in right before the PR step, but also to no avail.

```
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: '$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = ''$(user-pat)'''
```

(the same happened from above where it asked me to login if I removed the login step right after, and attempting to pipe it in also did nothing.)

And furthermore me reading from here suggests that its not possible to use a PAT from a secure variable like that here as it won't expand anyway: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/25206#issuecomment-1473554987

Any ideas on how I can get Authentication to work for making a Pull Request within Azure Pipelines when checkout occurs for any repo other than the one the yaml file for the pipeline is in?

Edit: Adding images showing permissions are set to what they need to have
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So apparently i'm not good enough at stackoverflow yet, to add comments, so i need to write an answer instead:

I have faced a fairly similar issue as you have:
[Azure Pipelines + Repos Rest API: Permissions for creating a Pull Request via API using System.AccessToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76462837/azure-pipelines-repos-rest-api-permissions-for-creating-a-pull-request-via-ap)

When using the System.AccessToken for your authentication the identity used is the Build scoped identities:

- [System.AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken)
- [Scoped Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scoped-build-identities)

so you might want to make sure that both you and the build identities (see answer on the question i have linked above) have the correct permissions on Repository B.

Comment: Wanted to note that I have seen this and am attempting to follow your remediations and adjacent ones when our admin is back to provide that access, and will update with results one way or the other

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my issues. All users should have the same permissions across all repositories. Both the `PROJECT Build Service (organization)` User and `Project Collection Build Service Accounts` Azure Devops Group have the same permissions of being allowed to Contribute, Contribute to Pull Request, Create Branch and Read. 

The issue is about the pipeline yaml being in a different repo, as I can put this pipeline in B and point to A and replicate the issue.

Comment: okay. unfortunate.

Is your Repo B in the same or a different project from repo A?

Under Project Settings -> Pipelines -> Settings there's various scope limiting settings that may interfere here.

Comment: Same Project. Its a Single Org / Single Project structure. I'll look into that space and see if there is something in those settings though

Comment: another thought: Have you explicitly set the repo you want to checkout as resource in your yaml? [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories-repository?view=azure-pipelines)

and does the pipeline have the correct permissions on the repo you want to checkout?
Project settings ->Repostory -> Settings -> Repo A/B ->Security -> Pipeline Permissions

Comment: Explicitly adding the repos did not change anything, and the System.AccessToken does not work. 

The PR command will not run if I don't do the AzDo login step, even if I put things in as environment variables.

I did confirm that both Repo A and Repo B have the same permissions as inherited from the project as a whole and should be accessible. 

Repo B already had my pipeline in the Pipeline Permissions, but I added the normal pipeline in each repo, and my hotfix pipeline each as trusted in both repos, and that still won't get SystemAccessToken to work.

Comment: I *was* able to get my user token to work before adding anything to that PipelinePermissions section, by granting it the ability to read 'Identity' to the same user token I was using to push the commit, but that option isn't visible for the Build Service or Build Accounts.

I would like to use the System Access Token still though, as I don't want to have to update this token every month to meet our security guidelines, and attribute changes to myself that were done by the script